# Visual Basic 2010 little error when using a Hashtable

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
 Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Membros WHERE NFamilia=@nfamilia", con)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nfamilia", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = nfamilia.Text

    con.Open()
    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    While (dr2.Read())
        Dim n As Integer = dr2(1)
        Dim nome As String = dr2(2)
        For i = 1 To 10
            table.Item(n).text = nome
        Next
    End While
    con.Close()
```

I have this code that will insert data in a Hashtable but I have a problem the dr2(1) it's an auto increment value and I get some thing like [this](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/374/semttuloiuo.png)

If I change the code to this:

```
            Dim n As Integer 
                n=1
                Dim nome As String = dr2(2)
                For i = 1 To 10
                    table.Item(n).text = nome
                    n=n+1
                Next
            End While
```

I get [this](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8061/semttulo1sfw.png)

If I make the code this way I get the same as above

```
        While (dr2.Read())

        Dim nome As String = dr2(2)
        For i = 1 To 10
            table.Item(i).text = nome
        Next
End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could yout try with this?

```
i = 1
While (dr2.Read())
    table.Item(i).text = dr2(2)
    i = i + 1
End While
```